# WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE can't change?

Tags: android

I'm using WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE to disable screenshot. Now is it possible to change the WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE instantly without reloading the activity?

for example:
I have a photo viewer using View Pager and I only want to disable screenshot to selected image . So can I change the flag secure by onPageChanged of view pager?

any thoughts will be highly appreciated.
thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use this code to clear the flag:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```